# How to restore SQL Server database backup to a newly created database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, smo, database-restore

I've a SQL Server 2005 database backup named `backupdb.bak`.I  want to restore it to database `MyDatabase`.

But before restoring I've to check whether `MyDatabase` already exists or not. If it does then I create a new database named `MyDatabaseNew` and I restore the backup file to this new database.

If I'm directly restoring the file into `MyDatabase`, the process is running fine. But when I'm checking the existence of `MyDatabase` and trying to create new database named `MyDatabaseNew`, it's giving error:

> Restore failed for Server servername

My code looks like this:

```
Restore restore = new Restore();
restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
CreateDatabase(MyDatabaseNew);
restore.Database = MyDatabaseNew;
restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem("C:\\backupdb.bak",DeviceType.File);
restore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseNewIntegrated Security=True;User ID=uid; Pwd=Pwd");
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);
sqlCon.Open();

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server smoServer = new Server(new  ServerConnection("."));
if (File.Exists("C:\\backupdb.bak"))
    // restore
    restore.SqlRestore(smoServer);
if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    sqlCon.Close();
```

and my create database (in case `MyDatabase` exists) code looks like this, where I'm passing `MyDatabaseNew` as a parameter for this method:

```
public void CreateDatabase(string NewDBName)
{
  string str;
  SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Integrated  security=True;
  database=master;User ID=uid;Password=Pwd");

  str = "CREATE DATABASE " + NewDBName + "";
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
  try
  {
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("New DataBase is Created Successfully", "Database Creation",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Database Creation", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
      myConn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Can any one tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When restoring to the new database, you need to use an equivalent of [Transact-SQL's `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH MOVE ...` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447.aspx) to specify new names for the data and log files:

```
restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("MyDatabase", @"c:\MyDatabaseNew.mdf"));
restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("MyDatabase_Log", @"c:\MyDatabaseNew.ldf"));
```

More information: [Getting Started with SMO in SQL 2005 - Restores](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=40)

Comment: no,still it's giving the same error "Restore failed for server servername"

Comment: Yes,I kept restore.sqlrestore(smoserver) in a try..catch block and here is the same error:--

Comment: base {Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject} = {[servername]}

Comment: ((Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server)(((Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException)(ex1)).FailedObject)).AuditLevel

Comment: BackupDevices = {Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupDeviceCollection}

Comment: if you want to know the detail information for a particular item,then let me know.I'll post the error details.

Comment: thanks Marek,Finally my code is working well..thank u very much

Comment: Actually at first I was trying to create a new database and assigning it the log and data file path of the old database..There it was giving trouble...So finally I made things simple...Now I'm restoring a database backup file(.bak extension) into the existing database..Before restoring I'm keeping a backup of the database and then restoring the backup file into the existing database..No new database is created now...

Comment: what if these files are not available Marek? I am using WCF to transfer .bak files. And there are no .mdf/.ldf files if the db does not exist already

Comment: @Tyler That's the idea of this command - the files should not exist, so the restore process can create files with such names. However, if you are restoring the database on a different server and want to keep the original name of the database and its files, you don't need to use `RelocateFiles` at all.

Comment: I found that in order to get around this, I had to create a db if it did not exist and then add the .mdf/.ldf files as in your answer. Would not work without them